# Android 2.2 SDK - Droid X Camera Activity doesn't finish properly

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-2.2-froyo

I noticed the default camera activity I call on a Droid X is different looking than the one on my Droid and Nexus One.  After selecting "OK" on the Droid and Nexus One, the activity would finish - the Droid X has a "Done" button (which takes you back to the Camera, instead of finishing the activity), and the only way to get to the screen I want is to hit the "Back" button.

Here is the class that works on Android 2.2/2.3, but not for Droid X's:

```
package com.android.xxx;

import java.io.File;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Window;

public class CameraView extends MenusHolder {

    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_event_view);
        /*
         * save to sd
         */
        File imageDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyPath/");
        imageDirectory.mkdirs();
        /*
         * temp image overwrites each time for space
         */
        _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/MyPath/temporary_image.jpg";
        startCameraActivity();
    }

    protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case 0:
            setResult(5);
            finish();
            break;
        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;
        setResult(0);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(CameraView.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CameraView.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude... it's just a bug. I had the same problem and there's no way to workaround that. It sometimes work, and sometimes it does not. I asked the Motorola's guy for help and they said that there's no support for those Android images.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a really really ugly workaround. I coded two functions to read and write files from sdcard (taken from here: http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=2035).

```
private boolean readFile() {
    try
    {
        File sd_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File f = new File(sd_path.getAbsolutePath(), "lock_camera_oncreate");

        BufferedReader fin =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(f)));

        String text = fin.readLine();
        fin.close();
        Log.e("Files", "Reading file");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Files", "Error reading file from SD Card");
        return false;
    }
}

private void createFile() {
    try
    {
        File sd_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File f = new File(sd_path.getAbsolutePath(), "lock_camera_oncreate");

        OutputStreamWriter fout =
            new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(f));

        fout.write("Semaphore test.");
        fout.close();
        Log.e("Files", "File writed");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Files", "Error reading file from SD Card");
    }

}
```

Then, in onCreate function, I make this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(readFile() == true)
    {
        File sd_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File f = new File(sd_path.getAbsolutePath(), "lock_camera_oncreate");
        f.delete();

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        return;
    }

    createFile();

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentImagePath)));
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}
```

The setRequestedOrientation call solves the issue when you are using your app in portrait mode, but when camera is launched, you put the mobile in landscape and then shoot the photo.

Then, the ugly readFile thing checks if a lock_camera_oncreate file exists and if it's true, 
then an additional onCreate call happened, so delete file and RETURN from this activity.

If activity advances, means the file's not created and there is only one camera activity running.

Hope it helps, it's ugly but worked for me :D