# Android: new activity is created after returning from camera instead of returning to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, instance

I have an activity A where you can press a button and choose between selecting a picture from the gallery and taking a new picture. When selecting a picture from the gallery everything is fine and the image is shown in the activity A. If you want to take a new picture, the camera app will be opened, you can take a picture and save it. And now the strange thing happens: instead of returning to the previous activity A from where you choose to take a picture, a new instance of activity A (A') will be created and launched. I don't know why it doesn't return to activity A...
Is its possible that activity A got a timeout and that's why a new instance will be created? Or any other ideas why a new instance is created?

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411009/activity-killed-oncreate-called-after-taking-picture-via-intent

Answer (score 0):

set

> android:noHistory = "true"

in MainActivity in

> AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

Use `startActivityForResult` to start camera activity. And when you want to come back t prev activity, just use `setResult` and call `finish()` for current activity.
You might be calling `startActivity()` again for activity A, so it was again getting created.
So try this and let me know it solves the problem. :)

Comment: In activity A I use startActivityForResult to start the camera. I don't know if I get it wrong, but doesn't the camera app set setResult and call finish?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you? Are you using default camera or custom camera?

Comment: Can you post your code? the code that starts camera and calls onActivityResult().

Comment: I'm using the default camera.
From activity X I launch activity A. When pressing a button I open a chooser (select image from gallery or take a new picture). After choosing "take a new picture" I open the default camera app with startActivityForResult. And after the user took a picture, the camera app finishes and return the image into the onActivityResult. so far so good. my problem is that after the camera app finishes I don't return to activity A but a new instance of activity A is created.

Comment: expected path: X --> A --> camera --> camera finishes --> A with the image in onActivityResult

but in my case: X --> A --> camera --> camera finishes --> new instance A' with image in onActivityResult