# Android Chooser intent in fragment to pic photo

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I ran into the following issue,

I have the following structure for my project,

1. There is a parent activity, which will host fragments (in total 3) inside it, layout as shown below,

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/processContent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_above="@+id/detSaveNContBtn" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. On the launch of the activity First fragment will be loaded, i.e, the framelayout (processContent) will be replaced by the fragment1, Fragment1 has a button, on click of that button, processContent will be replaced by Fragment2, in the same way Fragment3 gets loaded.

In the Fragment3, I have to upload multiple photos, that will be either with camera or from gallery.

So I am using chooser intent for displaying the choice, code for the same is as shown below,

```
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    SignUpProccessActivity activity = (SignUpProccessActivity) getActivity();
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    activity.setCapturedImageURI(fileUri);
    activity.setCurrentPhotoPath(fileUri.getPath());
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, activity.getCapturedImageURI());
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1888);
```

When I choose photo from a gallery all is well, but when I try to get image from camera, the activity's oncreate gets called, and hence again Fragment1 will be displayed.

I got to know that oncreate gets called when camera is called because the orientation gets changes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411009/activity-killed-oncreate-called-after-taking-picture-via-intent) question, as answered in the question I added the properties,

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But still the same issue.

what is that I am doing wrong in this.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I checked with by removing the gallery from the chooser, i.e just calling the camera intent after button click, if just camera is there then `onActivityResult` of the fragment gets called.

Comment: Instead of forcing the orientation, you should save your activity state and restore it again when onCreate is called. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: @adelphus: I have changed the code according to your comment. but still its the same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you observe is caused by the fact that the camera apps of some phones force screen orientation changes (and breaks your app as a side-effect - best at it is Samsung, which can force a couple of rotates at once). I learned that the only way to mitigate it is to save the activity (or fragment) instance state in `onSaveInstanceState()`

Another possible cause can be that while inflating fragments in activity, you don't check if `savedInstanceState` is not null. By not doing so, you inflate  new fragments (replacing old ones). The result is that, fragment's `onActivityResult()` is never called. (note though, that nested fragments are not supported).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer it worked perfectly for me. you Rock man!!