# Strange behaviour of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent - enters in onCreate when finishes

Tags: android

I am confused with ImageCapturing behaviour, but when I save photo ( phone is in portrait) from camera I always return in onCreate method. WHen I capture and phone is rotated 90 degree (landscape) it works fine and enter only in onResult and onResume

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageUri=Uri.fromFile(new File(imagesFolder,sfx));                  
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,122);
```

Can somebody tell me why ? I put in manifest in all activityies `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: Take a look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901752/android-2-2-sdk-droid-x-camera-activity-doesnt-finish-properly/8679892#8679892 I solved the question about additional calls to onCreate function with an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to add the following flags in all your Activities:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Android recreates the view if orientation changes. You need to add this to you Manifest file for the activity that calls the camera intent.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```